# C++ type of issue

Tags: c++, types, casting

Tour and GuidedTour. GuideTour extends Tour. I create a list of these items and add them to a vector.

```
 list = new vector<Tour>(); 
 list->push_back(Tour("FP001", "Fun Park 3 Day Pass", 110.00));
 list->push_back(Tour("BG002", "Botanical Gardens Entry Pass", 30.00));
 list->push_back(GuidedTour("SK003", "Learn to Ski Adventure Tour", 240.00, "28/07/2008", "Zail S", 25));
 list->push_back(Tour("OZ004", "Open Range Zoo Entry Pass", 45.00));
 list->push_back(GuidedTour("AB005", "Abseiling for Beginners Tour", 120.00, "15/07/2008", "Rex P", 35));
 list->push_back(GuidedTour("RA006", "White Water Rafting Tour", 200.00, "22/06/2008", "Clint R", 16));
```

Then I want to go thorugh this array and check the type of these Objects

```
void TourManager::callDisplayOnEach() {
    for (vector<Tour>::iterator it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); ++it) {
        if (typeid(*it) == typeid(GuidedTour)) {
            cout << "Guided Tour" << "\n";
        }
        else { 
            cout << "NOT Guided Tour : " << typeid(*it).name() << "\n"; 
        }
        //(*it).display();
    }
}
```

However it always returns NOT a Guided Tour option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering to Mat's link:

By storing a pointer to Base class there would be no slicing and you can achieve the desired polymorphic behaviour as well

So create a vector of

```
list = new vector<Tour*>();
```

Rather than

```
list = new vector<Tour>();
```

Answer (score 2):

As the comment above says, it is because of **slicing**. Since you store *values* in your `vector`, and not *references* or *pointers*, therefore when you **copy** the values into the container (yes, they are copied!), then every object is *truncated* to the base class `Tour`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers below that this is a slicing problem, althrough I would make it a vector of unique_ptrs so that it will manage the memory upon release for you. See below my version. Also, added a virtual destructor in the base class which is a good idea anytime you are referring to a derived class through a base pointer to avoid slicing if destructing via a base pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Tour
{

  public:
  Tour(const std::string& tt, const std::string& desc, double p  ) : tourType_(tt), description_(desc), price_(p){}

  virtual void display () const
  {
    std::cout << "Standard Tour" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual ~Tour() {};

  protected:
  std::string tourType_;
  std::string description_;
  double price_;
};

class GuidedTour : public Tour
{

  public:
  GuidedTour(const std::string& tt, const std::string& desc, double p, const std::string& date, const std::string& name, int age  ) : Tour(tt,desc,p), date_(date), guideName_(name), guideAge_(age) {}


  void display () const 
  {
    std::cout << "Guided Tour" << std::endl;
  }

  private:
  std::string date_;
  std::string guideName_;
  int guideAge_;
};


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tour> > v;

  v.emplace_back(new Tour("FP001", "Fun Park 3 Day Pass", 110.00));
  v.emplace_back(new Tour("BG002", "Botanical Gardens Entry Pass", 30.00));
  v.emplace_back(new GuidedTour("SK003", "Learn to Ski Adventure Tour", 240.00, "28/07/2008", "Zail S", 25));
  v.emplace_back(new Tour("OZ004", "Open Range Zoo Entry Pass", 45.00));
  v.emplace_back(new GuidedTour("AB005", "Abseiling for Beginners Tour", 120.00, "15/07/2008", "Rex P", 35));
  v.emplace_back(new GuidedTour("RA006", "White Water Rafting Tour", 200.00, "22/06/2008", "Clint R", 16));

  for ( auto& i : v )
  {
    i->display();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using C++98, so couldn't use this :(

Answer (score 0):

Like it is said, there is [**Slicing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

As you `vector` stores `Tour` object (Base class), all the derived object specific members of the object (`GuidedTour`) to be stored will get sliced off during the copy to act as Base class object.

The solution is to stores pointer of the base class :

```
std::vector<Tour*> list;
```

Since you are storing a pointer, there is no object copy anymore and no object slicing.

The best to do this would be to use [`smart pointers`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to do not have to do manually the memory management :

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tour>> list;
```

But if you use smart pointers, you will have to use [`std::vector::emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `push_back` :

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tour>> list;

list.emplace_back(new Tour);
list.emplace_back(new GuidedTour);
list.emplace_back(new Tour);
list.emplace_back(new GuidedTour);
list.emplace_back(new Tour);
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/4ulDBm).

But those techniques imply to use C++11.

Comment: I'm using c++98 so couldn't use this

Comment: @Archie Ok. However, at the begginning the method of `std::vector<Tour*> list;` still works :)